# Why is it possible to update UI using Handler created in a background Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a worker class which has a Handler created in it. When I try to update my UI using the handler created in background thread its updating the UI and there is no crash here. Ideally it should crash as its running in the background thread. Please find the code below:

```
class WorkerThread(val mainThreadHandler: Handler, handlerThreadName: String) :
  HandlerThread(handlerThreadName) {

  lateinit var workerThreadHandler: Handler

override fun onLooperPrepared() {
    super.onLooperPrepared()
    Log.d("LLoyd", "onLooperPrepared")


}


override fun run() {
    super.run()
    Log.d("LLoyd", "run method called")

}

fun startTask(){
    workerThreadHandler = object : Handler(this.looper) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            super.handleMessage(msg)
            Log.d(
                "Lloyd",
                "Message from Main Thread received " + msg.what + "  Thread name  " + 
currentThread().name
            )
            val message = Message()
            message.what = msg.what
            mainThreadHandler.sendMessage(message)
        }
    }

 }
}
```

This startTask() is called from activity on click of a button as below:

```
val workerThread = WorkerThread(mainThreadHandler, "Lloyd")
    workerThread.start()
    btn_task1.setOnClickListener {
        workerThread.startTask()
        val message = Message()
        message.what = FROM_MAINTHREAD
        workerThread.workerThreadHandler.sendMessage(message)
        val message1 = Message()
        message.what = 55
        Log.d("Lloyd ", "Outside Thread name " + Thread.currentThread().name)

        workerThread.workerThreadHandler.post {
            Log.d("Lloyd ", "Runnable Thread name " + currentThread().name)
            btn_task1.text = "Task 2"
            tv.text= "YAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAy"
        }
    }
```

Any kind of help is Appreciated!

Comment: Probably you create a handler with the main looper, so it's associated with the main thread. If  startTask() called in the main thread then so it's.

Comment: yeah, i agree with what @RevakoOA said, hope my answer makes that clear (and i hope it's correct)

Comment: Handler is not created with the main looper , its associated with HandlerThread. When I print the name of the Thread its showing the name of Background Thread .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you connect a Handler to your UI thread, the code that handles
>   messages runs on the UI thread.

taken from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui)

i believe because you're calling the `workerThread.startTask()` from the button click, which is the UI thread, the handler is simply returning the result to the UI thread as well, which is why the UI will update as well

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem for background tasks before. But Handler class is specifically create for updating UI in background tasks as Handler is in UI thread itself. For example, when you accomplish heavy task and need to update the ui you can do

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

               // here you perform background operation
               //Update the value background thread to UI thread
               mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                     // here you can update ui
                  }
               });
            }
         }
      }).start();
```

for more information you can also learn [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/mastering-android-handler-4f710296bdc6)

Comment: this does not answer what OP is asking. OP isn't asking how to update the UI, they're asking WHY is it updating

Comment: Plus for good link to read, still that's not the answer. Happy contribution!